# exporting to excel over https(SSL) using IE is not working in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, ssl, https, export-to-excel

i am trying to export an excel file from an https site, it is working great with 
firefox and other browsers but in IE its is giving me error  that the site is not available or the file is not found.

i have research the problem and i have found it is cache related so i have change the headers in this page so it will allow caching but it is still not working.

this is a snap of the code

Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(true);

```
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
    Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
    Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(true);

    Response.CacheControl = "Public";
```

any help would be great thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     #region For Download to work on HTTPS
```

> ```
>     Response.ClearHeaders();
>     Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
>     Response.Buffer = true;
>     Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
> ```

```
     #endregion
```

> ```
>     Response.Clear();      
>     Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Temp.xls");
>     Response.Charset = "";
>     Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
>     StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter();
>     HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(strWriter);
>     string heading = "<h4 align='left'>Temp Excel Cube</h4>";
>     strWriter.Write(heading);
>     gvTemp.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
>     Response.Write(strWriter.ToString());
>     Response.End();
> ```

I guess this is what you are looking for. It works for me on **HTTPS**, I've exported a grid to an excel sheet, you can use it to pickup a file from a physical location too.  :)